# Why I keep getting null exception after the objects finished moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoidFlocking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 velocity;

    private float cohesionRadius = 10;
    private float separationDistance = 5;
    private Collider[] boids;
    private Vector3 cohesion;
    private Vector3 separation;
    private int separationCount;
    private Vector3 alignment;
    private float maxSpeed = 15;

    private void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("CalculateVelocity", 0, 1f);
    }

    void CalculateVelocity()
    {
        velocity = Vector3.zero;
        cohesion = Vector3.zero;
        separation = Vector3.zero;
        separationCount = 0;
        alignment = Vector3.zero;

        boids = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, cohesionRadius);
        foreach (var boid in boids)
        {
            cohesion += boid.transform.position;
            if (boid == null)
                print("It's null !!!!!");

            alignment += boid.GetComponent<BoidFlocking>().velocity;

            if (boid != GetComponent<Collider>() && (transform.position - boid.transform.position).magnitude < separationDistance)
            {
                separation += (transform.position - boid.transform.position) / (transform.position - boid.transform.position).magnitude;
                separationCount++;
            }
        }

        cohesion = cohesion / boids.Length;
        cohesion = cohesion - transform.position;
        cohesion = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(cohesion, maxSpeed);
        if (separationCount > 0)
        {
            separation = separation / separationCount;
            separation = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(separation, maxSpeed);
        }
        alignment = alignment / boids.Length;
        alignment = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(alignment, maxSpeed);

        velocity += cohesion + separation * 10 + alignment * 1.5f;
        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.position.magnitude > 25)
        {
            velocity += -transform.position.normalized;
        }

        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, separation, Color.green);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, cohesion, Color.magenta);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, alignment, Color.blue);
    }
}
```

I added this part now for checking but boid is never null:

```
if (boid == null)
                    print("It's null !!!!!");
```

The null exception is on the line:

```
alignment += boid.GetComponent<BoidFlocking>().velocity;
```

I have 5 spheres with the same script attached to it and Velocity set in all to X = 1 Y = 1 Z = 1

I tried to learn the tutorial here:

[Boid and birds in Unity3D](https://unionassets.com/blog/boid-and-birds-in-unity3d-296)

But I can't figure out why I'm getting the null exception.

Comment: Wich of the null related Exceptions do you get precisely? Right now you ahve 2 commands (a chain of member accesses) in the same line. Please split them over multiple lines using temporary variables to better localise the point of error. Do not be worried about performance. The JiT Compiler is really good at cutting out such "useless" variables in release builds.

Comment: Check value returned from `GetComponent<BoidFlocking>()`. Most likely that is null.

Comment: You could change your condition to: `if (boid?.GetComponent<BoidFlocking>() == null)`, which tests both `boid` and the return value of `GetComponent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't matter to be null, then just write it this way:

```
alignment += boid?.GetComponent<BoidFlocking>()?.velocity ?? Vector3.zero;
```

This line says, if `boid` or `GetComponent<BoidFlocking>()` are null, then use `Vector3.zero` as a default value.

Comment: I'm getting this error:  Feature 'null propagating operator' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 6 or greater

Comment: Well, then enable .net 4.6 to get access to C# 6. To enable .net 4.6 support go to Edit->Project Settings->Player->Other Settings->Configuration->Scripting Runtime Version and set the "Api Compatibility Level*" to .NET 4.6

Comment: @DanielLip alternatively, check `if (boid.GetComponent<BoidFlocking>() == null)`, becuase boid doesn't need to be null in order for it to not have a `BoidFlocking` component attacked.

Comment: The whole point of `?.` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators is to eliminate null checks when you don't care if it's null. You wanna do `if (something == null)` only if you care and you wanna do something about it.